# Edit method, doing multiple checks for tracking changes vs the one in database

Tags: java, performance

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which there are around 2-3 methods which are quite big and complex, but only one of them worries me, especially for maintenance or changes. As changes in the method can immediately change some critical functionality in the project. The application is basically a Note-taking application, and takes as input a lot of parameters, and fans out to external services, different views.

The method I am worrying is about editing a Note object. For that, I have to do multiple checks and accordingly take action. I have managed to break down the method into 3 parts, but the core of it still remains tacky at best. How can I proceed with simplification. I am pasting the method for reference sake, cannot go into details of what is actually happening.

Code:

```
@Override
    public String editGroupNote(GroupNotes noteObjectFromUser, int msectionId) {

        if (noteObjectFromUser.isPrivateNoteFlag()) {
            createPrivateNote(noteObjectFromUser, msectionId);
            return "privacychange";
        }
        Person person = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();

        NoteSelection noteSelection =
                this.noteSelectionService.checkIfSelectionValid(noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid(),person.getId());
        boolean checkIfEvernote = (noteSelection != null);
        String latestText = noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext();
        noteObjectFromUser.setMnotetext(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext().replaceAll("\\s*id=\"cke[^\">]*\"",""));

        String newText = "";

        GroupSection retrievedSection = this.groupSectionService.getGroupSectionById(msectionId);
        GroupCanvas ownedCanvas =  this.groupCanvasService.getCanvasById(retrievedSection.getCurrentCanvasId());
        GroupAccount ownedAccount = this.groupAccountService.getGroupById(ownedCanvas.getGroupAccountId());
        GroupNotes databaseNoteObject = this.groupNotesDAO.getGroupNoteById(noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid());
        GroupMembers loggedInMember =  this.groupMembersService.returnMembersMatchingUsernameAccountId(person.getUsername(),
                        ownedAccount.getGroupId());

        String oldText = databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext();
        String oldTag = databaseNoteObject.getMnotetag();

        databaseNoteObject.setMnotetext(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext().replaceAll("\\s*id=\"cke[^\">]*\"",
                ""));
        if ((loggedInMember.isAccesslevel())) {

            noteObjectFromUser.setCreatorId(databaseNoteObject.getCreatorId());
            noteObjectFromUser.setMnotetext(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext().replaceAll("\\r?\\n","<br/>"));
            noteObjectFromUser.setMnotetag(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetag().replaceAll("\\r?\\n","<br/>"));
            noteObjectFromUser.setNoteCreatorEmail(databaseNoteObject.getNoteCreatorEmail());

            boolean noEdit = false;
            GroupNoteHistory groupNoteHistory = new GroupNoteHistory();

            if (!(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext().equals(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext()))) {
                if (isLineDifferent(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext(),
                        noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext())) {
                    diff_match_patch diffMatchPatch = new diff_match_patch();

                    LinkedList<diff_match_patch.Diff> deltas = diffMatchPatch.diff_main(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext(),
                            noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext());
                    diffMatchPatch.diff_cleanupSemantic(deltas);
                    newText += diffMatchPatch.diff_prettyHtml(deltas);
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
                    noEdit = true;
                }

                newText = newText.replaceAll("<li>", "<div class=‘list‘>");
                newText = newText.replaceAll("</li>", "</div>");
                groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newText);

                groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(Jsoup.clean(newText, Whitelist.basic()));
                groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
            }


            if (!(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotecolor().equals(databaseNoteObject.getMnotecolor()))) {
                if (noEdit) {
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                } else {
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("colorchange");
                    groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage(databaseNoteObject.getMnotecolor());
                }
                groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage(part1 + noteColorSubject + part2 + noteObjectFromUser.getMnotecolor() + part3);
                noEdit = true;
            }
            if
                    (!(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetag().equals(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetag()))) {
                groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteHeadline(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetag());
                if (noEdit) {
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                } else {
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("tagchange");
                    groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteHeadline(noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetag());
                    groupNoteHistory.setOldHeadLine(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetag());
                }
                noEdit = true;
            }

            if (!(noteObjectFromUser.getZugwisenPersonId() == databaseNoteObject.getZugwisenPersonId())) {

                if ((databaseNoteObject.getZugwisenPersonId() != 0) && (noteObjectFromUser.getZugwisenPersonId() == 0)) {
                    Person zugweisedPerson = this.personService.getPersonById(databaseNoteObject.getZugwisenPersonId());
                    if (!noEdit) {
                        noEdit = true;
                        groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("zugweised");
                        groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage("Zuweisung von " +
                                zugweisedPerson.getFirstName() + " entfernt");
                    } else {
                        groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                        noEdit = true;
                    }
                    updateStatisticsForZugweisen(zugweisedPerson.getId(), false, ownedAccount.getGroupId(),
                            ownedCanvas.getMcanvasid(), noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid());
                } else {
                    Person zugweisedPerson = this.personService.getPersonById(noteObjectFromUser.getZugwisenPersonId());
                    if (!(zugweisedPerson == null)) {
                        noteObjectFromUser.setPersonWhoZugweised(person.getId());
                        if (!noEdit) {
                            groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("zugweised");
                            groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage("Hat die Note " + zugweisedPerson.getFirstName() + " zugewiesen");
                            noEdit = true;
                        } else {
                            groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                            noEdit = true;
                        }
                        updateStatisticsForZugweisen(zugweisedPerson.getId(), true, ownedAccount.getGroupId(), ownedCanvas.getMcanvasid(), noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid());
                    }
                }
            }
            boolean gantt = false;

            if ((noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget() == null) && (noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null)) {
                if (databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget() != null) {
                    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                    noEdit = true;
                    gantt = false;
                }
            } else {

                if ((noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null) && (!(noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget() == null))) {
                    if (databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget() == null) {
                        noEdit = true;
                        gantt = false;
                    } else {
                        Date fromUserDate = new Date(noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget().getTime());
                        Date savedDate = new Date(databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget().getTime());

                        if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate)) {
                            groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                            noEdit = true;
                        }

                        if (savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {
                            groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
                            noEdit = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                    if ((!(noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget() == null)) ||
                            (!(databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget() == null))) {

                        if ((noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget() != null) &&
                                (databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget() == null)) {
                            if (!noEdit) {
                                gantt = true;
                            }
                            noEdit = true;
                        } else if ((noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget() == null) && (databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget() != null)) {
                            if (!noEdit) {
                                gantt = true;
                            }
                            noEdit = true;
                        } else if ((!(noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget() ==
                                null))) {

                            Date fromUserDate = new Date(noteObjectFromUser.getNoteTarget().getTime());
                            Date savedDate = new Date(databaseNoteObject.getNoteTarget().getTime());


                            if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate)) {
                                if (!noEdit) {
                                    gantt = true;
                                }
                                noEdit = true;
                            }

                            if (savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {
                                if (!noEdit) {
                                    gantt = true;
                                }
                                noEdit = true;
                            }

                        } else {

                            Person zugweisedPerson = this.personService.getPersonById(noteObjectFromUser.getZugwisenPersonId());
                            if (!(zugweisedPerson == null)) {
                                groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("zugweised");
                                groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage("Hat die Note " + zugweisedPerson.getFirstName() + " zugewiesen");
                                gantt = !noEdit;
                                noEdit = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    if ((!(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null)) ||
                            (!(databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() ==
                                    null))) {

                        if ((noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() != null) &&
                                (databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() ==
                                        null)) {
                            if (!noEdit) {
                                gantt = true;
                            }
                            noEdit = true;
                        } else if ((noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() ==
                                null) &&
                                (databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() != null)) {
                            if (!noEdit) {
                                gantt = true;
                            }
                            noEdit = true;
                        } else if
                                ((!(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null))) {

                            Date fromUserDate = new Date(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());
                            Date savedDate = new Date(databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());

                            if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate)) {
                                if (!noEdit) {
                                    gantt = true;
                                }
                                noEdit = true;
                            }

                            if (savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {

                                if (!noEdit) {
                                    gantt = true;
                                }
                                noEdit = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!(databaseNoteObject.isPrivateNoteFlag() ==
                    noteObjectFromUser.isPrivateNoteFlag())) {
                groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("privacychange");
            }
            if (noEdit) {
                noteObjectFromUser.setNoteCreationTime(databaseNoteObject.getNoteCreationTime());
                noteObjectFromUser.setNoteCreatorEmail(databaseNoteObject.getNoteCreatorEmail());
                noteObjectFromUser.setMnotetext(latestText);
                databaseNoteObject.setMnotetext(oldText);
                this.groupNotesDAO.editGroupNote(noteObjectFromUser,
                        msectionId);

                if (checkIfEvernote) {
                    this.evernoteService.pushNoteToEvernote(noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid());
                }

                groupNoteHistory.setMnoteEditDate(new
                        Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                groupNoteHistory.setEditorId(person.getId());

                if (!gantt) {
                    this.groupNoteHistoryService.addNoteHistory(groupNoteHistory,
                            noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid());
                    this.noteActivityService.saveGroupNotActivity(noteObjectFromUser.getMnoticesid());
                }

                noteObjectFromUser.setActiveEdit(false);
                noteObjectFromUser.setNoteDate(noteObjectFromUser.getNoteDate());

                GroupSection groupSection = this.groupSectionService.getGroupSectionById(msectionId);
                int canvasId = groupSection.getCurrentCanvasId();
                GroupCanvas groupCanvas = this.groupCanvasService.getCanvasById(canvasId);
                Long groupAccountId = groupCanvas.getGroupAccountId();
                this.unreadNotesService.deleteEntriesForAnote(databaseNoteObject.getMnoticesid());
                this.notificationService.deleteNotificationsForNote(databaseNoteObject.getMnoticesid());

                sendOutNotifications(groupAccountId, groupCanvas, groupSection, noteObjectFromUser, groupNoteHistory, person.getId(), person.getUsername(), person.getFirstName(),
                        groupNoteHistory.getWhatHasChanged(),
                        groupNoteHistory.getChangedMessage(), gantt, oldTag);
                return "edit";
            } else {
                return "nochange";
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

This is just the core part. And changes to it are extremely tricky and consume time in tests. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you please edit your title to summarize what your code does/is about? We all want to improve our code on this site, so stating that you do in the title is not helpful. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PinCrash : Done. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate)) {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
    noEdit = true;
}

if (savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
    noEdit = true;
}
```

This sort of thing can be merged:

```
if (savedDate.after(fromUserDate) || fromUserDate.after(savedDate)) {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
    noEdit = true;
}
```

You might want to use `!savedDate.equals(fromUserDate)`, if that works the same as checking if either is bigger than the other.

---

Another example:

```
if (!noEdit) {
    noEdit = true;
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("zugweised");
    groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage("Zuweisung von " +
            zugweisedPerson.getFirstName() + " entfernt");
} else {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
    noEdit = true;
}
```

If both cases end up with `noEdit` as true, move it out of the if-statement.

```
if (!noEdit) {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("zugweised");
    groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage("Zuweisung von " +
            zugweisedPerson.getFirstName() + " entfernt");
} else {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
}
noEdit = true;
```

Failing that, at the very least remove it from the else case - you KNOW it is true, there is no reason to set it to true again.

---

```
if (!noEdit) {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("zugweised");
    groupNoteHistory.setChangedMessage("Hat die Note " + zugweisedPerson.getFirstName() + " zugewiesen");
    noEdit = true;
} else {
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("generalchange");
    noEdit = true;
}
```

Same here...

I think if you went through the code and cleaned mini-messes like those, you could chop off a quarter of the complexity.

---

```
if ((loggedInMember.isAccesslevel())) {
```

This check at the start, it wraps most of your code...

For starters, you have one pair of parentheses too many. Let's strip those:

```
if (loggedInMember.isAccesslevel()) {
```

Next, what you do when this if statement fails is

```
return "";
```

So given the rather large amount of indentation, I'd suggest that you'd negate the if statement and turn it into a guard clause:

```
if (!loggedInMember.isAccesslevel()) {
    return "";
}
```

Then the rest of your code can be indented one level less.

Heck, you might even be able to move this guard clause up, thus saving a bit on performance for that case. Performance isn't the main reason to do this though; Identifying guard clauses allows you to move them away from the code doing the actual work.

---

```
if ((!(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null)) ||
    (!(databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() == null))) {

    if ((noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() != null) &&
        (databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() == null)) {
        if (!noEdit) {
            gantt = true;
        }
        noEdit = true;
    } else if ((noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null) &&
               (databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() != null)) {
        if (!noEdit) {
            gantt = true;
        }
        noEdit = true;
    } else if ((!(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null))) {

        Date fromUserDate = new Date(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());
        Date savedDate = new Date(databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());

        if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate)) {
            if (!noEdit) {
                gantt = true;
            }
            noEdit = true;
        }

        if (savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {

            if (!noEdit) {
                gantt = true;
            }
            noEdit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

hmmm... looks suspicious.

Let's use a truth table. First, define the values...

```
noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() = A
databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() = B

A == null = Anull
B == null = Bnull
```

Then simplify the code...

```
if (!Anull || !Bnull) {

    if (!Anull && Bnull) {
        if (!noEdit) {
            gantt = true;
        }
        noEdit = true;
    } else if (Anull && !Bnull) {
        if (!noEdit) {
            gantt = true;
        }
        noEdit = true;
    } else if (!Anull) {

        Date fromUserDate = new Date(A.getTime());
        Date savedDate = new Date(B.getTime());

        if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate) || savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {
            if (!noEdit) {
                gantt = true;
            }
            noEdit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I took the liberty of applying an earlier made suggestion.

Okay, so... the truth table:

```
Anull | Bnull | !Anull |!Bnull|(!Anull||!Bnull)|(!Anull&&Bnull)| (Anull&&!Bnull)
  0   |   0   |    1   |  1   |        1       |       0       |      0
  0   |   1   |    1   |  0   |        1       |       1       |      0
  1   |   0   |    0   |  1   |        1       |       0       |      1
  1   |   1   |    0   |  0   |        0       |       0       |      0
```

And the last case, (the elseif of the elseif of the if inside the if)

```
(!Anull||!Bnull) && (!(!Anull && Bnull) && !(Anull && !Bnull)) && !Anull
1
0
0
0
```

So for `0, 0` and `0, 1` and `1, 0` we enter the if statement, for `0, 1` and `1,0` we perform the check for setting `gantt`, and... the last statement is for when both are not null.

So, basically, rephrased:

> If `Anull` and `Bnull` differ, run the simple check. If they are both false, run the complex check.

So use that!

```
if ((noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() == null) 
 != (databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() == null)) {
    if (!noEdit) {
        gantt = true;
    }
    noEdit = true;
} else if(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() != null 
       && databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() != null){
    Date fromUserDate = new Date(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());
    Date savedDate = new Date(databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());
    if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate) || savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {
        if (!noEdit) {
            gantt = true;
        }
        noEdit = true;
    }
}
```

Look at how much shorter it is! Next, encapsulate conditionals:

```
boolean hasStartFromUser = noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp() != null;
boolean hasStartFromDB = databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp() != null;

if (hasStartFromUser != hasStartFromDB) {
    if (!noEdit) {
        gantt = true;
    }
    noEdit = true;
} else if(hasStartFromUser && hasStartFromDB){
    Date fromUserDate = new Date(noteObjectFromUser.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());
    Date savedDate = new Date(databaseNoteObject.getStartDateTimestamp().getTime());
    if (fromUserDate.after(savedDate) || savedDate.after(fromUserDate)) {
        if (!noEdit) {
            gantt = true;
        }
        noEdit = true;
    }
}
```

Now it's readable too.

---

```
if (isLineDifferent(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext(),
        noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext())) {
    diff_match_patch diffMatchPatch = new diff_match_patch();

    LinkedList<diff_match_patch.Diff> deltas = diffMatchPatch.diff_main(databaseNoteObject.getMnotetext(),
            noteObjectFromUser.getMnotetext());
    diffMatchPatch.diff_cleanupSemantic(deltas);
    newText += diffMatchPatch.diff_prettyHtml(deltas);
    groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
    noEdit = true;
}

newText = newText.replaceAll("<li>", "<div class=‘list‘>");
newText = newText.replaceAll("</li>", "</div>");
groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newText);

groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(Jsoup.clean(newText, Whitelist.basic()));
groupNoteHistory.setWhatHasChanged("textchange");
```

This is the ONLY place you use `newText`! Move your variable declaration over to this section of code.

Comment: I am making changes as you are editing, thank you. This and 2 others just became complex over time, and contained code which could change behaviour easily. I am also looking for some strategies to avoid creating such complex methods in future,.. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg I'd prefer if you could post a followup question once you're done incorporating my feedback - I'm pretty sure there's more comments I could make, but I'm interested in seeing how it looks with all the changes applied right now and I don't feel like putting in the time needed for making the full edit myself. This was basically step 1 of cleaning; step 2 would be identifying stuff that can go into separate functions.

Comment: Okay, I have already incorporated the changes you mentioned, but will again go through and find if there is something I missed out and post a follow up question. Thanks a lot.  :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg had one more; now I'm done. I still see some point I want to make but I'll save them for next time. Let me know when you've posted the followup =)

Comment: Okay, the last 2 changes I saw together now, not incorporated, will surely post the link. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Hi, I have posted a new question as follow-up. Kindly check out this link : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123195/java-edit-method-optimizing-and-minimizing-method-to-reduce-complexity